# How can I read some number of lines from the middle of a CSV file into a new file?

Tags: linux, shell

how would one retrieve line number 101 to 200 from the file and write these lines into a new CSV file? say the file name is file.csv and the name of the new CSV file is supposed to be newfile.csv in the Linux shell

Comment: There is neither a Linux shell nor a Linux terminal, there are multiple shells and terminals available. Please read the descriptions of the tags you apply! Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick

```bash
sed -n -e 1p -e 101,200p file.csv > newfile.csv
```

---

**Explanation:**

sed is used to extract lines from a text file:

- `-n` to suppress the default output
- `-e 1p` to print the first line (the header of the CSV file)
- `-e 101,200p` to print from the line 101 to 200

Finally, the output is redirected to `newfile.csv` using `>`.